# JQuery dialog to pass back true or false to submit function

Tags: jquery, forms, dialog, modal-dialog

I am using the submit function in Jquery to do some validation, if the validation is true it submits the form. However, I've added an 'are you sure' dialog. Can I pass back true or false from the dialog which would then submit the form as currently I'm stuck in a loop.

JQuery:

```
$(function(){
<!-- form validation -->
$("#form1").submit(function() {     

  //validation stuff

  //Disable the submit button 
  $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', false);



  // Only if true is returned from dialog??
  return true;
}) });
```

html

```
<div id="testdialog" title="Please Check">
<p>Are you sure></p>                            
   <div style="height: 30px; width:100px;"onclick="$('#testdialog').dialog('close');return true;">
Continue
   </div>
   <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;" onclick="$('#testdialog').dialog('close');return false';">
Redo selection
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dialogs are asynchronous, you can't return anything from them.

Comment: You need to use the `onClick` callbacks of the dialog buttons to perform the actions you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set a global/session variable that tells you if the user has already confirmed or not, something like this:

```
var confirmed = false;
var confirmSubmit = function() {
    $('#testdialog').dialog('close');
    confirmed = true;
    $("#form1").submit();
    return true;
}
$(function(){
     <!-- form validation -->
     $("#form1").submit(function() {     

     //validation stuff

     //Disable the submit button 
     $('#SubmitButton').attr('disabled', false);

     if (!confirmed) {
        // Trigger the notification
     }


     // Only if true is returned from dialog??
    return confirmed;
}) });
```

and the html:

```
<div id="testdialog" title="Please Check">
    <p>Are you sure></p>                            
    <div style="height: 30px; width:100px;"onclick="confirmSubmit">
       Continue
    </div>
    <div style="height: 30px; width: 100px;" onclick="$('#testdialog').dialog('close');return false';">
       Redo selection
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice it near enough sorted the issue out. I had problems getting the onclick="confirmSubmit" to work and decided to use a listener instead.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the advice it near enough sorted the issue out. I had problems getting the onclick="confirmSubmit" to work and decided to use a listener instead.

```
$(function(){
     $('#btnconf').click(function() {
     $('#testdialog').dialog('close');
     confirmed = true;
     $("#form1").submit();
     return true;
   });
```

In the html I added id="btnconf" to the button.

Hey presto!! works a treat!. Thanks again!